# How to create script for AWS Glue Job using CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, aws-glue3.0

I am trying to write a CloudFormation template for glue job. I see that there is no option available in official documentation to use apply mapping feature just like we see in the console. How can we use the same feature in our template?
I know that AWS can automatically generate a script for us when we create a job using console, I want to know if AWS will generate the script for us when we create glue job using CloudFormation template?
If yes, then how can I generate the script? Please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used to write CFN Templates in the past too and considered this sometimes as a hard job. In my experiance I've learned to go trough the required parameters from the CFN Doc [(here GlueJob)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-job.html) and try to implement them. When I had no idea on how to do that I just used the GitHub search function and looked up how others did that. That is exactly what I recommend You here. Have a look on [these search results](https://github.com/search?l=YAML&q=AWS%3A%3AGlue%3A%3AJob&type=Code).
Maybe You find some samples helpful for Your usecase:

- [Sample 1](https://github.com/otsuki-masafumi/sf-samples/blob/d99dc2640cf4e1cd3e6a121910c5bbb66b410fec/jobflow-A/glue-jobs.yaml)
- [Sample 2](https://github.com/Renek1992/etl_aws_glue_pipelines/blob/17fda984775dc0adbc5e04cc94719038b07f6f73/deploy/GlueETL.yaml)
- [Sample 3](https://github.com/094459/devopsworld-airflow/blob/f75aa6df1806558f97cd46b49e6bf11bddbfe462/demos/demo-02-localdev/git-precommit-demo/cloudformation/stack.yml)

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me out. I want to know if AWS can generate a job script if we create glue job using template or we have to provide the script upfront for our job.

Comment: If You mean the python scripts then You have to provide them by Yourself. You have to provide a the full path to S3 where the script is stored. Again: check the samples.